# What happens if I set no rivals?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

**What happens if I set no rivals?**

It's obvious there are no more chances to gain power projection, but otherwise, is there any harm to not having any rivals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No other side effects.  However, power projection is amazing.  Set rivals.  Crush them!

Comment: Indeed, no side effects besides missing out on the rival bonuses and power projection bonuses. So don't worry, if you happen to be unable to choose any rivals.